# Spring Security what's the difference between http.authorizeHttpRequests() and http.requestMatchers()

Tags: spring-security

What's the difference between these configurations:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

And

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
               
        http.requestMatchers().and().authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

When should we use `http.authorizeHttpRequests()` or `http.requestMatchers()`

Comment: I am still confused! It is clear in the case where we specify extra rules after ` http.requestMatchers()` but it is not clear for the case defined in my question. I mean when we don't specify any specific url.

Comment: @akuma8 *I mean when we don't specify any specific url.* Then you can remove `.requestMatchers()`, because it makes no sense. It makes only sense if you have at least one better more than one URLs.

Comment: @dur As said in my last comment, I opened another question about Spring Security please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085572/spring-security-why-specifying-full-paths-to-secure-when-we-have-a-base-path