# Why specifying full paths to secure when we have a base path?

Tags: spring-security

Say we have this configuration:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMatching(("/private")
class PrivateProductController {

  @GetMapping("/products")
  Collection<Product> getProducts(){
    ....
  }

  @GetMapping("/category")
  int getCategory(){
    ....
  }

  @GetMapping("/catalog")
  Catalogue getCatalogue(){
    ....
  }
}
```

And an associated security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/private/**")
                .and()
            .authorizedRequests()
                .antMatchers("/private/products").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/private/category").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/private/catalog").hasAnyRole("USER","GUEST");              
    }
}
```

Since the base path is `/private/**` I tried to simplify my configuration like this (by removing `/private` from subpaths):

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/private/**")
                .and()
            .authorizedRequests()
                .antMatchers("/products").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/category").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/catalog").hasAnyRole("USER","GUEST");              
    }
}
```

But that simplification does not work. So the question is why do we need to add each time the full path? Since we declared this:  `http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/private/**")` I thought that all `/private` subpaths like `/products` or `/category` would be managed in this filters chain without prefixing them by `/private`.
I surelly misconfigured spring security, how to achieve what I would like to do? I mean defining a filters chain matching a base path where all subpaths are protected without needing to prefix them by the root path? Thanks

Comment: If you add more than one `.antMatchers("/private/**")` , what would be the base path? Spring Security wouldn't know. That's the reason you have to configure the whole path again.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you passed to `antMatcher` method is matched by Spring Security with the request URI  i.e. `request.getServletPath()+request.getPathInfo()+request.getQueryString()`

When you provide just `/products` instead of `/private/products` , the pattern doesn't match and it fails.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to achieve what I would like to do?

Comment: Try `.antMatchers("/**/products").hasRole("USER")`

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao In this particalar case it would work, but if you have `products` again in the path tree, like `/private/great/products` it would also match. That could be not intended.